# Is there a comparable php function like exif_imagetype for other files

Tags: php, security, file-upload

The php `exif_imagetype()` function seems to be the most reliable way of determining an image type as it actually reads the first byte and then tells you the image type.

For other files, like videos, documents, etc. is there a way of securely doing this? You obviously can't rely on `$_FILES['file']['type']`, as the mime header type can easily be spoofed.

Comment: All popular file types have a file signature <https://www.filesignatures.net/index.php?page=all> has a rather large list, i am not aware of any php function,but you could write your own that checks your supplied file against a list of file signatures

Answer (score 1):

[Fileinfo](https://secure.php.net/fileinfo) with the `FILEINFO_MIME` flag is your best bet.

But have it in mind that there *will* be false positives. Unfortunately, there just isn't a realiable way to validate file types ...
Certainly, not for every single filetype there is, and while not technically impossible to have your own validation for at least a few common types, it would be a *very* intensive process, as you'd have to validate literally every byte within a file.

This isn't limited to PHP, it's just how things are with file handling. I wouldn't entirely trust `exif_imagetype()` either.